# icefaces 3.0 ace:dataTable sorting column,need example

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I need an example for sorting a column in ace:dataTable, i don't know how to use sortBy + sortFunction .
thanks

Comment: Off topic but IceFaces is a fork of PrimeFaces, in case you don't know. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ui:param name="title" value="#{msgs[dataTableSorting.title]}"/>
<ui:param name="description" value="#{msgs[dataTableSorting.description]}"/>
<ui:param name="resourceValue" value="#{dataTableSorting.exampleResource}"/>

<ui:param name="wikiResources" value="#{dataTableResources.wikiResources}"/>
<ui:param name="tldResources" value="#{dataTableResources.tldResources}"/>

<ui:define name="example">
    <h:form id="form">
       <ace:dataTable id="carTable"
                      value="#{dataTableSort.carsData}"
                      var="car">
           <ace:column id="id" headerText="ID" sortBy="#{car.id}">
                <h:outputText id="idCell" value="#{car.id}"/>
            </ace:column>
            <ace:column id="name" headerText="Name" sortBy="#{car.name}">
                <h:outputText id="nameCell" value="#{car.name}"/>
            </ace:column>
            <ace:column id="chassis" headerText="Chassis" sortBy="#{car.chassis}" >
                <h:outputText id="chassisCell" value="#{car.chassis}"/>
            </ace:column>
            <ace:column id="weight" headerText="Weight (lbs)" sortBy="#{car.weight}">
                <h:outputText id="weightCell" value="#{car.weight}"/>
            </ace:column>
            <ace:column id="accel" headerText="Accel" sortBy="#{car.acceleration}" >
                <h:outputText id="accelCell" value="#{car.acceleration}"/>
            </ace:column>
            <ace:column id="mpg" headerText="MPG" sortBy="#{car.mpg}">
                <h:outputText id="mpgCell" value="#{car.mpg}"/>
            </ace:column>
            <ace:column id="cost" headerText="Cost" sortBy="#{car.cost}">
                <h:outputText id="costCell" value="#{car.cost}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency"
                                     currencySymbol="$"
                                     groupingUsed="true"
                                     minFractionDigits="2"
                                     maxFractionDigits="2"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </ace:column>
        </ace:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Reference - [icefaces-showcase](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dataTableBean)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example,  I need to know how to connect sortby and sorFunction to the java code , can you please give me the example of the java code that implement this xhtml code ? ( I don't understand how to pass sortBy values and use it in the java code )

Answer (score 2):

So my friend found the solution:

In the collectionBean :

```
private Comparator<String> vNoComparator = new Comparator<String>(){ 

         public int compare(String iRec1, String iRec2){
              if(iRec1==null || iRec2==null)
              {
                    if(iRec1==null && iRec2==null)
                          return 0;
                    if(iRec1==null)
                          return -1;
                    return 1;
              } 

              long vNumber1=  Long.parseLong(iRec1) ;
              long vNumber2= Long.parseLong(iRec2);
              if(vNumber1>vNumber2)
                    return 1;
              else if(vNumber1<vNumber2)
                    return -1;
              else        
                    return 0; 
        }
  };
```

The type of Comparator is the type of the attribute that we sort by , in this case ARecordNo  type is String

```
public Comparator<String> getvNoComparator() {
        return vNoComparator;
  }
  public void setvNoComparator(Comparator<String> vNoComparator) {
        this.vNoComparator = vNoComparator;
  }
```

In .xhtml :

```
  <ace:dataTable
  value="#{eITDocumentsCollectionBean.AEITDocumentsItems}"
  var="eITDocumentsItemBean" …..
  <ace:column
  headerText="#{eITDocumentsCollectionBean.ARecordNumberColumnName}"
  sortBy="#{eITDocumentsItemBean.ARecordNo}" 
  sortFunction="#{eITDocumentsCollectionBean.vNoComparator}">
```

ARecordNo= the attribute in the ItemBean to sort by it
vNoComparator= the Comparator I create